# How to plot elswhere than in main frame (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter, plot, frames

I am fairly new to python or coding in general. I tried to find a solution to my problem but after hours of googling I still could not find a solution to my problem. Therefore, I hope someone here can help me. Also, I am not looking for the smartest solution to y problem, rather to a solution that is easy to understand for a newbie like me.

So, my problem:
I have already some code to calculate different things. This is all working fine. I now would like to create a rather advanced GUI with tkinter where I can implement my calculations etc. The GUI should have several pages, all with different options for calculations and one graph.
I used he example from Bryan Oakley (found here in the forum) for the pages. That's all working fine. My Problem is how can I create a graph that is only present on each individual page. The way I did it so far, the graph is always shown in the main frame, above the individual pages. Also in that way the program gets stuck in a kind of loop, so that the code is still running although I close the main window.
Hope you understand what I am trying to ask for ^^

Pleas find the (shorten) code that I am using below. It's quite long, but as I said I am rather new to that stuff and I dont know how to describe my problem more precisely.

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()
        
class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global var1,var2,var3,var4
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.configure(bg="lightblue")
                      
        self.B_load = tk.Button(self,text = "load data", fg = "black", height = 2, width = 20).place(x=10,y=10)
                
        var1 = tk.IntVar()
        self.c1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Show all samples (var1)', bg='lightblue',variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1, width=22, anchor='w',command=Var1).place(x=10, y=260)
       
        Application()

class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
         
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        
        #self.configure(bg="black")
        
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        
        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        
        
        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        
        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Main", command=p1.lift)
        b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Basic Rock-Eval", command=p2.lift)
              
        b1.pack(side="left")
        b2.pack(side="left")
        p1.show()   
        
def Var1():
    global var1
    print("Var1=",var1.get())
    
class Application(tk.Frame):
 
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4)) 
        canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=root)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=250,y=50)
        canvas.draw()

    def plot(self):
        ax1.clear()        
         
        FID= [1,2,3,4]
        T= [1,2,3,4]
        ax1.set(xlim=(0,len(FID)),ylim=(0,max(FID)*1.1))
        ax2.set(ylim=(0,max(T)+50))

        ax1.plot(y_1,x,'grey')
        ax2.plot(y_2,x,'r')
        canvas.draw()

root = tk.Tk()
main = MainView(root)
main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.wm_geometry("1150x700")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First you need to pass `self` when creating instance of `Application`, like `app = Application(self)`, and call `app.place(...)` as well. Second you should use `master=self` instead of `master=root` in `FigureCanvasTkAgg(...)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help. It's working now =)